# Bootstrap container width to match a web page size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container for carousel and I wanted its length and width to be according to the webpage size. I tried using "container row" it only aligned to the left of the webpage but the width is not extended.

How can I go about doing it?
This is an example of what I wanted (the purple colour div) http://getbootstrap.com/css/.

```
<div class="container row"> 
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

<!-- item 1 -->
<div class="item active">
<img src="img/Nielsen.png" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h4>Jacob Nielsen's 10 usability principles </h4>
<p>Most used for evaluation of user interface usability</p></br>
</div>
</div>

<!-- item 2 -->
<div class="item">
<img src="img/UIParade.png" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h4>UI Parade - User Interface Design Inspiration</h4>
<p>Ui Parade has good UI reference!.</p></br>
<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="http://www.uiparade.com/">Learn 
more</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: See http://www.bootply.com/hirro/93060 (not mine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                 Your content
            </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just read the post about container vs container fluid. Container-fluid is more smooth if user is manually changing the width of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    Your content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```